# Unable to import module when using paramiko sshclient

Tags: python, paramiko

When trying to execute a python file through a paramiko SSHClient, I'm getting the error:

```
ImportError: No module named rospy
```

In the line of that file that contains the rospy import.  I'm only getting this error when trying to run the code using paramiko i.e:

```
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(ipaddress,22,username,pw)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python path/to/file.py')
```

When executing the command through a terminal, it works as desired. I only get the import error when trying to use paramiko.  I'm unsure as to why this is occurring and any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Edit: further tinkering and experimentation has shown that it is a path issue, but the path for both the computer I am using and the target device are the same, but when I run echo $PATH on paramiko, the path element /opt/ros/indigo/bin/ is not included

Comment: Have you successfully tested running exec_command() with a simple Python file (e.g., a file that doesn't import any modules)?

Comment: You might need to install the rospy module of the targeted machine if the python distribution is different.

Comment: yeah simple commands such as 'pwd' and 'ls' work fine

Comment: Also the targeted machine has python 2.7.6 while mine has 2.7.12, could that be the root of the issue?

Comment: I strongly suspect it has to do with the search path for modules, which could differ for your script's SSH session versus your terminal-based SSH session. For example, is your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable set on the target machine so scripts (local to the target machine) can import `rospy`? If this is the case, and assuming you're using a recent version of paramiko, you can pass an environment variable dictionary to `exec_command`